# get div height which has floated div inside

Tags: html, height, floating

I have a div with ID "containter" which contain 3 div with floated left property.
When I use these floated div, the "container" div don't get height based on insided Div.
What is the solution?
Thank.

Comment: Try to set `overflow:hidden` on the container element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put clear property to restore the flow.
[My Codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/pgLGE)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="coucou" ></div>
  <div class="coucou" ></div>
  <div class="coucou" ></div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
  width : 600px;
  background:pink;

}

.coucou {
  margin-left:2px;
  width :100px; 
  height:200px;
  float: left;
  background:blue; 
}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

Comment: I understood otherwise. Edited but it's the same solution.